# jQuery's attr() escaping ampersands

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, escaping

So i'm trying to set an image src attribute dynamically via javascript like so:

```
var url = 'query.php?m=traffic&q=getgraph&id='+pipeId+'&start=-3h';
console.log(url);
$('#3h').attr('src',url);
```

The problem is, it shows up like so `query.php?m=traffic&q=getgraph&id=1&start=-3h` in the console, the the actual set src for the #3h image element is `query.php?m=traffic&amp;q=getgraph&amp;id=1&amp;start=-3h`

And then, of course, it doesn't work. How do I avoid jQuery's attr() methods' character escaping? Any other suggestions on how should I achieve my goal are very welcome as well.

Comment: `&amp;` is HTML for `&` (while `&` is HTML for *Start an entity*). So why "of course, it doesn't work"? This is expected behaviour and it should work. What URL do you see in the access logs for the server? What URL do you see requested for the image in Firebug or another network monitoring tool? The character escaping is done internally by DOM, not by the jQuery wrapper. (Actually, it is done on the way out when serialise back to HTML)

Comment: @David Dorward: I meant "it doesn't work" by testing it out by pasting http://blahblahblah.com/query.php?m=traffic&amp;q=getgraph&amp;id=1&amp;start=-3h (it doesn't work like that) and http://blahblahblah.com/query.php?m=traffic&q=getgraph&id=1&start=-3h (this one does work)

Comment: So to test it you copied an HTML attribute and tried to use it as a URL? That won't work. You need to convert the HTML into text to get a URL out (and converting to text will turn `&amp;` back to `&`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it doesn't work, it's not due to the ampersands being escaped. As an attribute in an HTML element, all XML entities need to be escaped:

```
--+-------
< | &lt;
> | &gt;
" | &quot;
& | &amp;
```

As an example, if I had `index.php?foo=bar&buzz=baz`, and I wanted to have an `a` element target that page, I would need to set the anchor like so:

```
<a href="index.php?foo=bar&amp;buzz=baz
```

The href would get decoded as: `index.php?foo=bar&buzz=baz`

I'll see if I can't find the relevant documentation for you.

Comment: This is technically correct, but I've never heard of a browser that complains about an unescaped ampersand in your href attribute

Comment: HTML is flexible, browsers are supposed to *try* to figure out what you meant. They don't always get it right, which is why you *should* escape your attributes. JavaScript will do it automatically.

Comment: Try having `http://example.com/?foo=bar&copy=baz` — then watch as `&copy` gets parsed as `©`. Browsers will try to error recover from invalid entities.

Answer (score 2):

The only issue that I see in your code is that your ID attribute is starting with a number, which is invalid in HTML4.

```
$('#3h') // invalid for HTML4
```

You should change the ID on the element to begin with a letter, like `h3`

```
$('#h3') // valid ID for HTML4
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it's working:

http://jsfiddle.net/y249K/

Answer (score 0):

You can `escape` the data before writing it to an attribute.
Try out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wmPK8/)

```
 $('#3h').attr('src', escape(url));
```

then

```
unescape($('#3h').attr('src'))
```

Answer (score -1):

You could avoid using jQuery for this and use native JavaScript/DOM functions instead:

`document.getElementById('3h').src = url;`

Comment: But like David mentioned, this is expected behavior, so either method should work just fine.

Comment: this native JS does the same thing, it also escapes the src